# How to change the style of the tab in android tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

I want to change the style of the tab in android `tabhost`, I don't want to change the color of background only, but the whole style ( to make rounded corners for example) .

Answer (score 0):

In `TabHost` you can put a `Button` or any other widget with a preferred style, even with rounded corners

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("My Button");
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
myButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.my_button_drawable_top, 0, 0);
TabHost.TabSpec myButtonTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(myButton).setContent(intentPlayList);
mTabHost.addTab(myButtonTab);
```